Unity Custom Class List Serialisation with Enum Type
I am trying to serialise a list of a custom class in Unity's inspector. This class contains a enum type of PlayerOptionType. However, whenever I try to add a instance of this to the list in the inspector, the list disappears from the inspector and the console loops constantly outputting the following error.

My code is below:
Base Class
using UnityEngine;

public class Base : MonoBehaviour // A base class that all items, maptiles and objects inherit from
{
    [SerializeField]
    internal ObjectType objectType;

    public ObjectType ObjType { get { return objectType; } }
}

ItemBase Class
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemBase : Base // A item base class that all game items inherit from
{
    [SerializeField, Header("Item Base Options")]
    internal bool interatable;
    [SerializeField]
    internal List<PlayerOption> interactions; // The List of the custom class I want to serialize
    [SerializeField]
    internal bool isTileBlocker;
    [SerializeField]
    private float fadeTime;

    [SerializeField, Header("Misc Properties")]
    internal bool isVisible;

    internal MeshRenderer meshRenderer;

    public bool IsTileBlocker { get { return isTileBlocker; } }

    public virtual void InitaliseItem()
    {
        isVisible = false;
        meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshRenderer.enabled = false;
    }

    public virtual void SetVisible(bool visible)
    {
        isVisible = visible;
        meshRenderer.enabled = visible;
    }
}

PlayerOption Class
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class PlayerOption // The custom class I want to serialize, stores data of a game object and what type of action a player can make with it
{ 
    [SerializeField]
    private string description;
    [SerializeField]
    private PlayerOptionType type;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject target;

    public string Description { get { return description; } }
    public PlayerOptionType Type { get { return type; } }
    public GameObject Target { get { return target; } }

    public PlayerOption(PlayerOptionType type, GameObject target, string description)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.target = target;
    }
}

I have other areas of my project that have serialised enums that display in the Inspect fine. Adding them to a serializable class though creates this issue. Sometimes Unity will work temporarily allowing me to add/remove and instance or two from the list then it will start throwing this error again.
I have tried making the fields public, adding a new empty class constructor, setting a default value for the enum and adding the [serializable] tag to the enum definition among other things. None of them seem to fix the issue at all.
Edit:
Adding more clarification PlayerOptionType is the enum that I think is the cause of the issue and looks like this
public enum PlayerOptionType
{
    Null,
    Player_Attack,
    Player_Interact,
    Player_Move
}

Adding the full error to the post, looks like this

Edit 2:
After taking a look at the first error thrown, it seems it is different from all the following errors
NullReferenceException: SerializedObject of SerializedProperty has been Disposed.
UnityEditor.SerializedProperty.get_intValue () (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.ListViewSerializedObjectBinding.UnbindListViewItem (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement ve, System.Int32 index) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.ListViewController.UnbindItem (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, System.Int32 index) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CollectionViewController.InvokeUnbindItem (UnityEngine.UIElements.ReusableCollectionItem reusableItem, System.Int32 index) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VerticalVirtualizationController`1[T].ReleaseItem (System.Int32 activeItemsIndex) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.DynamicHeightVirtualizationController`1[T].ReleaseItem (System.Int32 activeItemsIndex) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VerticalVirtualizationController`1[T].Refresh (System.Boolean rebuild) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.DynamicHeightVirtualizationController`1[T].Refresh (System.Boolean rebuild) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVerticalCollectionView.RefreshItems () (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CollectionViewController.set_itemsSource (System.Collections.IList value) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVerticalCollectionView.set_itemsSource (System.Collections.IList value) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.ListViewSerializedObjectBinding.ClearListView () (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.ListViewSerializedObjectBinding.Release () (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.RemoveBinding (UnityEngine.UIElements.IBindable bindable, System.Boolean forceRemove) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.Unbind (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.DefaultSerializedObjectBindingImplementation.UnbindTree (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.DefaultSerializedObjectBindingImplementation.Unbind (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.BindingExtensions.Unbind (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.PropertyField.Reset (UnityEditor.SerializedProperty newProperty) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.PropertyField.Reset (UnityEditor.UIElements.SerializedPropertyBindEvent evt) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.PropertyField.ExecuteDefaultActionAtTarget (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEventAtTargetAndDefaultPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <7c69dfc1e63a4ea388c73014d3c7ce20>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.SendBindingEvent[TEventType] (TEventType evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement target) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.BindPropertyRelative (UnityEngine.UIElements.IBindable field, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.BindTree (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.BindTree (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.BindTree (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.ContinueBinding (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.Bind (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.DefaultSerializedObjectBindingImplementation.Bind (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedObject obj) (at <8c3449848bd845499081ddbe4a09b367>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.BindingExtensions.Bind (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedObject obj) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.InspectorElement.SetEditor (UnityEditor.Editor value) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.EditorElement.Reinit (System.Int32 editorIndex) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.PropertyEditor.ProcessEditorElementsToRebuild (UnityEditor.Editor[] editors) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.PropertyEditor.DrawEditors (UnityEditor.Editor[] editors) (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.PropertyEditor.RebuildContentsContainers () (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.RedrawFromNative () (at <9920ff0c944845d7b9f9a61ef1478edc>:0)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

I can provide additional information in further edits if required.
Edit 3:
My question was closed and referenced to the article explaining what a NullReferenceException is. I don't think this matches my question as my question is in relation to the serialisation of objects to display in Unity's visual inspector instead of a core Object Orientated Programming fundamental. What am I doing wrong for Unity to be throwing the errors doing when trying to serialise the class in the inspector?
After suggestions from comments, I have tried the same code I provided in a new project and didn't have the issue so there is clearly something else in the project that causes the error when trying to serialise the custom class.

Please add the complete error, especially the first one, to your question. And what is PlayerOptionType? Is it the same as PlayerOptionsType?

Thanks, I'll update the post now.  But answering your questions briefly, 'PlayerOption' is the custom class that I want to serialise and 'PlayerOptionType' is the enum that I think is the issue

Whoops, that is indeed a typo. I'll correct that now thanks

Can you take a look at the first error in the console? Maybe it's different. It is also best to add the error in the form of plain text.

Taking a look, and you're right. The first error is different, I'll add it to the post as plain text and bear that in mind for future, thank you

I'm not 100% sure how Unity handles those cases, but since you want your PlayerOption class to be serializable in the inspector, it should have a parameterless constructor as well. In C# when you don't define any constructor it automatically has a parameterless constructor. However when you manually add a parameterized constructor, there will be no implicit parameterless constructor. It's possible that Unity doesn't care but it may be the issue so Unity can't create an instance of your class.

Unity handles parameterless constructors in the background so you don't need to create them yourself. I did try this though in case it was the issue as well as adding default values to each property but it made no difference unfortunately

I tried to reproduce this issue, but unfortunately the inspector worked very well. Whether the GameObject is in the scene or in the assets, adding and deleting items to the interactions list succeed. Have you tried creating a brand new project to test? I guess this error seems to be caused by the destruction of the ItemBase instance during inspecting, so maybe this is caused by other code.

I haven't tried making a brand new project, I will try that later on and get back to you on if it resolves the issue thanks

Have you also tried to use a different name for the Null enum entry? It might be an issue regarding string based serialization ...

Do you mean setting the enum's default value to something other than Null? I have just tried that but not had any luck with it unfortunately. I haven't yet tried this is a new project though as Shingo suggested. Only just got back to my PC and its late here so will likely be something to test tomorrow

I meant just rename it to e.g. None .. however an issue here might be that values could have already been serialized using Null as value (though I'm almost sure it is something else and enums are serialized by their int value)

I also tried now - apologies: it seems indeed Unity doesn't require the parameterless constructor .. works just fine without. That said: It works just fine for me using just your provided code snippets ... so this is either caused by some custom editor at another place .. or just a Unity hickup that will be resolved on next startup

Thanks, appreciate the help. I have tried restarting Unity and that didn't help, but copying the code into a new project did indeed get it working so there's clearly something else in the project that's at play. Frustrating but at least its narrowing down the potential causes
